# Computing ratio $ \frac{\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n} d x}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n+1}dx} $ by other means than Beta integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, beta-function

For any positive numbers $k$ and $n$, converting the integral
$$
I_{n}:=\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n} d x
$$

into a Beta Function by letting
$y=x^{k}$, gives  $d x=\frac{1}{k} y^{\frac{1}{k}-1} d y$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{n} &=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{k} y^{\frac{1}{k}-1}(1-y)^{n} d y \\
&=\frac{1}{k} B \left(\frac{1}{k} , n+1\right) \\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}\right) \Gamma(n+1)}{k \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}+n+1\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then the ratio becomes
$$
\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_{n}}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}\right) \Gamma(n+2)}{k \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}+n+2\right)} \cdot \frac{k \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}+n+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}\right) \Gamma(n+1)}
$$

Using the identity $\Gamma(z+1)=z \Gamma(z)$, we can simplify the ratio
$$
\frac{\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n} d x}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n+1}dx}=1+\frac{1}{k(n+1)}
$$

---

By the way, $$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n} d x}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n+1}dx}= \lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n} d x}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n+1} d x}=1
$$

***My Question:*** Is there any method other than Beta Function?   Your opinion and alternative method is warmly welcome.

Comment: $\int (1-x^k)^n\,dx=x\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{k},-n;1+\frac{1}{k};x^k\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate by parts

\begin{align}
I_{n+1}=&\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n+1}dx\\
=&\>k(n+1) \int_{0}^{1}x^k\left(1-x^{k}\right)^{n}dx
= k(n+1) (I_n-I_{n+1})
\end{align}
which is $
\frac{I_n}{I_{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{k(n+1)}
$.

Comment: Thank you for your simplest solution!